# encryption of jndi in glassfish4

Tags: java, encryption, glassfish, glassfish-4

I've found that it had encrypted jndi in glassfish3 as shown in [cloveretl](http://doc.cloveretl.com/documentation/UserGuide/index.jsp?topic=/com.cloveretl.server.docs/docs/encrypted-jndi.html)

However once I use it in glassfish4, I found that it always comes out with the warning :
`Error in dealiasing the password ${ALIAS=passwd}: Alias  passwd does not exist|#]`

However, I found that the alias `passwd` has in the alias properties :

`root@63cf8620c529:/usr/local/glassfish4# asadmin  list-password-aliases
passwd
pass
Command list-password-aliases executed successfully.`

It's really bothered me at this time ....